# Spring boot don't mapping exist table which in MS SQL

Tags: java, spring

I have Spring boot project where we use MS SQL JPA Java EE and Spring boot. We have tables which we need to use for example one of the tables is "Dept". When we run our project spring trying creat dept but our MS SQL DB exist this table but the name is Dept. The Spring trying creat table with the first letter with lowercase. But the table which I need mapping the first letter with a capital. And spring mustn't create the table because I have the table already in MS SQL.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider defining a global naming strategy. By default, table names are bound using lowercase identifiers. However, adding in your application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physicalstrategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

you will be able to follow the uppercase first letter table naming strategy you desire.

More information about naming strategies can be found in [Hibernate reference](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/naming.html)

Comment: Or use the `@Table(name = "Dept")` annotation.